# Data connection enable/disable code crashes inside a android service

Tags: android, service, crash, connection

```
void turnData(boolean ON)
 {
   final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
   final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
   iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
   final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
   final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
   final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
   setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
   setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
}
```

The above code is to enable/disable Data Connection in android 2.
3+.
It works without any errors when I run it in an Activity. But when i tried to run it inside a service the application crashed. Can anyone tell me why this happened?

Comment: Looks like a problem in your Manifest file. Have u given proper permissions? Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: I have given proper permissions on manifest file.
Logcat output:
07-25 10:11:21.506: E/(2024): java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10034 nor current process has android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE.
07-25 10:11:21.716: E/(2024): java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10034 nor current process has android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE.
07-25 10:11:21.736: E/(2024): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the following additional permissions to the Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: "android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" can only be granted to System  Apps. So to toggle data connection, phone must have root access? Is there a way to do it without a rooted phone?

Comment: That permission is not required. Please see the updated answer.