# How to turn off 3G data connection programmatically in android?

Tags: android, dataservice, 3g-network

I want to Enable/Disable 3G and other Data connections separately.Is it possible to access 3G individually?That means if the user selects the option 3G, then Enable/Disable 3G data connection only.And if the user selects the option Data Services, enable/disable data connections except 3G.Is it possible?
 I tried the following methods
       
     `enableDataConnectivity();` 
        
**and**

`disableDataConnectivity();`

**of** 

`TelephonyManager`

But i think these methods turn off/on all data services in whole.I want to access 3G separately.

How to do this?

Comment: Did you look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535101/how-can-i-turn-off-3g-data-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: Ofcourse.I think it turn off/on all data Connections.Am i right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code sample should work for android phones running gingerbread and higher:

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) 
{
   final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)    
   final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)
   context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
   final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
   iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
   final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
   final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =     Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
   final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
   setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
   setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

This also requires the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Is it possible to enable/disable 3g data connection individually?

Comment: no buddy this is for 2g as well as 3g , it turn off all Data connection

Comment: @Neal your code is not working, see this similar thread "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646871/data-connection-enable-disable-code-crashes-inside-a-android-service"